# how to make decrypt(human readble file) to mongodb.log.gz

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, atlas

I want to see the log file of MongoDB I have downloaded from MongoDB but when I opening I can see something encrypting text there so I am not able to understand.
please tell me how I make it readable or if I am doing anything wrong please make me correct

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `.gz` is a Linux compressed file that you are trying to open in Notepad.
Convert your file to `.zip` using for example https://convertio.co, and try to open it.

Maybe you will see the right file?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).